# Problem on Ubuntu 10.04, I am in only one group --root, cannot use synaptic or sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

```
abc@ubuntu:~$ groups
root

abc@ubuntu:~$ sudo bash
[sudo] password for abc: 
abc is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I get this error on launching synaptic: "Failed to run /usr/sbin/synaptic as user root.
The underlying authorization mechanism (sudo) does not allow you to run this program. Contact the system administrator."

Can you help ?

Comment: not a stackoverflow question. try askubuntu or superuser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reboot into recovery mode and edit the sudoers file with nano or something.

Comment: Logging into recovery mode and editing /etc/group worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

`sudo visudo` to put the user in sudoers file. you can do `echo 'abc ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers`

Comment: You did not read the question carefully. I said I am not in sudo group.

Comment: abc@ubuntu:~$ sudo visudo  
[sudo] password for abc:   
abc is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: Above solution did not work. abc@ubuntu:~$ echo 'abc ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
bash: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied

Comment: You can do `su` to get the root shell. and then enter `echo 'abc ALL=(ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers` or `su -c 'echo "abc ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers'`

Comment: @Neel Basu How can one su if he can't do sudo? Is it possible?

Comment: sudo's just a shell around su, for the most part.

Comment: Ya sometimes when sudo doesn't work su works. and su needs root password. su doesn't need you to be in /etc/sudoers I donno about others distros. but I've seen this in debian. and once I was left with a fedora years ago. there sudo didn't work but su worked.

Comment: `su [username]` allows you to change to the given user (or root when no arguments are supplied) using that users password.  `sudo` allows you to execute commands with higher privilege using your current users password IF it is listed in the `sudoers` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to boot from live CD and add "abc ALL=(ALL) ALL" to /etc/sudoers. It must help.

P.S It just a guess.

Comment: For this simple job you gonna use Live CD ?? WoW

Comment: I think Live CD is my only option. @Neel Basu, if you have a better solution, then please let us all know. Meanwhile I will go with @Ashot Martirosyan's approach.

Comment: are you sure that `su` is not working ? `su` will ask for your root password. can you just run `su` and tell me its response ? it should give you a root shell with `#`

Comment: @Neel In case of Ubuntu - there is no working root account, if you don't set password by hand you cannot use `su` to switch to that account.

Comment: This solution should work fine.  Another option that works well is copy over the root password from another box by copying the right line in `/etc/shadow`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo

@Tanath: you should never edit the sudoers file directly! That kind of thing causes the above problems. Always use a command like visudo to edit this file (the program will check that the formatting is correct, etc)